Problem deploying Azure Function Code to a FunctionApp Slot using yaml (zip not found)
I am building an Azure Function in C# and wish to deploy using pipeline.
I build once, test, then publish.
Then, for each ENV, I run a bicep file to setup infrastructure and immediately after I wish to deploy the published Function Code to the (single) Function App.
I get an error trying to deploy from the published zip file. The file can't be found. What am I doing wrong?

Example of published file:

[command]/usr/bin/zip -r /home/vsts/work/1/s/build272.zip

(The log lines seem reasonable)
Error seen :

##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/a/*.zipCheck if the package mentioned

Note that we publish from /1/s and try to find it in /1/a
The build has 'attached' artifacts as 'drop/build272.zip
(The 11MB file seems reasonable)
yaml lines to publish:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "dotnet publish"
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
    projects: 'src/**/*.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files (into zip)"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Publish build artifacts"
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'

yaml lines to deploy :
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1 # Add this at the end of your file
  displayName: 'Deploy Function code to FunctionApp Slot'
  inputs:    
    azureSubscription: 'ServiceConnection'
    appType: functionAppLinux # default is functionApp
    appName: 'f2404dev-app'
    package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'


There are not enough details to understand what is going on - are you trying to generate the deployment package and deploy it in the same job? Or in different jobs/stages?

Hi Rui, problem solved -- and it was in different Stages. Thanks for chipping in...

It seems that you are missing the download artifact step
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    itemPattern: '**/*.zip'
  downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

Reference: https://sterl.org/2023/03/azure-devops-function-app-deployment-no-package-found/

Yes, that solved it -- thanks! I also had to make a change in the deployment step where  in the 'package' value, I was missing ** for directory. I've update code above for anybody stumbling over this question in the future.
REALLY AWESOME! I'm now running my first Function made & deployed from scratch.

Glad to hear that Anders!
